# How to redirect page in react after form validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am new to JavasScript, so what I have probably is not the best way, so hopefully someone can correct me! I have a form which sends data to express through an ajax call.

```
<Form  name="FlightForm" id="FlightForm"  action="/search" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  >



      <div >
 <label>FROM</label>
 <input required  type='text' name='originOne' id="originOne"  onChange={this.setState.originOne}  className="form-control" placeholder="Departing from"/>
        </div>


<div>
  Departure Date 
 <DatePicker className="form-control" required minDate={new Date()} name='date' selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

</div>



    <p><button type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="true" onSubmit={this.loading()} className="w3-button w3-dark-grey">Search for destinations</button></p>


</Form>
```

```
export class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.state = { originOne: '', originTwo: '', redirectToResult: false, startDate: new Date(), route:'', loader:false};


      this.onSubmit= this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.setMulti=this.setMulti.bind(this);
      this.loading=this.loading.bind(this);

    }


onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
       originOne: e.target.value, originTwo: e.target.value, 
       route:e.target.value});
    };


 setMulti  = event => {
         this.setState(
             {route: event.target.value});
     };

 onSubmit = (e) => {

     e.preventDefault();
     const { originOne, originTwo , route} = this.state;
    this.setState({ loading : true});
     {this.loading()}
};

 handleChange(date){
     this.setState({
         startDate:date
     });
 }
```

At the moment I have an ajax call to submit the data to server which is referenced in the index.html page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
        $("#search").on('click', function(){
            // send ajax
            console.log($("#FlightForm").serialize()) ;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $("#FlightForm").serialize(), // post data || get data
                success : function(data, status, xhr ) {


                   window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/searching");

                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log("Error happening");
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/error");
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I have structured it to redirect to a searching page with a loading spinner once submitted, however this overrides the required fields for the form validation.

What is the best way to go about submitting the form after form validation and redirect to the next page? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!